# Image size are getting shrinked while printing in pdf using iText

Tags: java, itext

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(filePath);
image.setSpacingAfter(10f);
image.scaleAbsolute(100f, 100f);
PdfPTable imageTabel = new PdfPTable(1);
imageTabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
image.setScaleToFitHeight(true);
PdfPCell cellOne = new PdfPCell(image, true);
cellOne.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cellOne.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(255, 255, 255));
imageTabel.addCell(cellOne);`
columnText.addElement(imageTabel);
```

In PDF few images are not printing properly.

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Originally I wanted to stop here and provide the same amount of information like you did... Please give us more information. Some observations: (1) In your code you do `image.scaleAbsolute(100f, 100f);` thus scale the image to an absolute width and height of 100x100. But in the screenshot it seems that you stretch the image over the full page. Of course this looks ugly. Additionally you say "few images" so others are working? ...

Comment: If we have multiple images to print in pdf, sometimes like the above example one image size is getting cropped too small image.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example and show the complete code required to run it?

Comment: Ah, so you mean in your screenshot shows a big image and a small image? So the big one is correct? And the small one depicting a screenshot is incorrect? Please be more specific and provide more details/code - we are all guessing here!

Comment: Yes Lonzak, a small image is the issue. i had provided the code block which we am using to insert the image in pdf

Comment: @Saran your code has e.g. reference to `columnText` - what do I provide there? Can you attach the image as well? Without the minimal and reproducible code sample chances are, no one will be able to help. The code is minimal now, but not reproducible unfortunately